# Django: redirect from page if model field is certain value

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a Class-based-view that sends a user to a webpage to view an item. The user can click on the edit button to edit the page, however, I don't want the user to always be able to edit the page. Once a field ('status') in a model has been set to 'completed', I'd like the user to no longer be able to update the page. I have a class based view. How do I redirect the user to a different url, (e.g. the view url) if the status=completed? My current approach is to have a form that errors if the field status is set to completed. It's not ideal since the person still sees the edit an may wonder why it is erroring out.

urls.py

```
url(r'^update/(?P<status_id>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/$', ThingUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
```

class based view

```
class ThingUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model      = Thing
    form_class = ThingChangeForm
    template_name = 'thing/thing_update.html'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to override `render_to_response` method to handle `GET` requests and `form_valid` to handle `POST` and `PUT`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class ThingUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model      = Thing
    form_class = ThingChangeForm
    template_name = 'thing/thing_update.html'

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        if self.object.status == 'completed':
            return redirect('some-view-name') 
        return super().render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs) 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.object.status == 'completed':
            return redirect('some-view-name') 
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be that you use Javascript for this purpose. Set the value of the form element to "completed" and run the **JS function window.location()** to redirect the user if the value is set to "completed".